# How to use the result of stored procedures in the same stored procedure for other function

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, output, insert-into

I have created two tables

**tbl1**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl1] 
(
    [Costumer ID] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [Name of the Costumer] [NVARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Contact Number 1] [NCHAR](11) NULL,
    [Contact Number 2] [NCHAR](11) NOT NULL,
    [Email Id] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Address] [NVARCHAR](1000) NOT NULL,
    [Dust] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [M.sand] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [6MM] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [10MM] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [40MM] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NOT NULL,
    [Bolders] [NUMERIC](18, 0) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

**tbl2**:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl2]
(
    [DCN] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Party] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Material] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Rate] [NVARCHAR](4000) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [UK_tbl_intedrlink_dcno] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DCN] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

and created a stored procedure as fallows

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
    @mat NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @party NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @rate NVARCHAR(1000); 

    SET @sql ='select  ['+@mat+']   from tbl1'+ ' where [Name of the Costumer] = @party' set @params = '@party nvarchar (1000)'  exec sp_executesql @sql, @params,@party= @party

    INSERT INTO tbl2([Party], [Material], rate) 
        SELECT @party, @mat, @rate
END
```

When I execute the stored procedure, I want insert the values into `tbl2`, which is directed from `tbl`.

But when I execute the stored procedure, I get the result as follows

[image]

In `tbl2`, the `rate` column is being added as null, where I wanted to take result of `sp1` (stored procedure), and insert the value into the `rate` column.

I had not set `@rate` to a value, I want to set the result of `exec sp_executesql` as the `@rate` value

Can anyone help to solve the problem?

Comment: Show me the part where you actually set @rate to a value; I may be being blind but I can't see it in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp1]
    @mat NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL,
    @party NVARCHAR(1000) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @params NVARCHAR(4000); 
    DECLARE @rate NVARCHAR(1000); 

    SET @sql ='select  @rate = ['+@mat+']   from tbl1'+ ' where [Name of the Costumer] = @party' 
    SET @params = '@party nvarchar (1000), @rate NVARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT'  

    EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params,@party= @party,@rate = @rate OUTPUT

    INSERT INTO tbl2([Party], [Material], rate) 
        SELECT @party, @mat, @rate
END
```

You can add one more parameters to `sp_executesql` stored procedure.

Like `@rate` as an `OUTPUT` parameter and you will get return value from executed stored procedure to direct into your declared variable.

Hope it will help.

Comment: i want @rate value is to be take from the result

Comment: i dont want to add the rate manually , rate value should the result

Comment: i want @rate vale is to be take from the result of sp_executesql , to insert into tbl1